# Invoker’s Right function result caching

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having trouble in understanding how the `result_caching` works when the `authid` of the function is set to `current_user`. What were the restrictions with result_caching, when Oracle introduced this feature in 11g and how this feature has changed since then?
Any relevant material for reading will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: "*Any relevant material for reading*" - That would be [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/memory-architecture.html#GUID-675AAFFB-E915-4197-8159-C0CF1C009973)

Comment: Other than oracle docs, please. I need information for function result_cache when used with the invoker's rights.

Comment: From Oracle 11g documentation one of the restrictions is `It is not defined in a module that has invoker's rights or in an anonymous block.`

Comment: Yes, and invoker's rights restriction has been removed in Oracle 12c, and from further releases, what they have implemented to remove this restriction?

Comment: What do you mean with "Other than oracle docs, please"?